# Company-latex-commands doesn't show completion

Tags: latex, company-mode

I don't know why in an org buffer, where `company-math-symbols-latex` and `company-latex-command` backends are added to the backends list and company is activated, the command `company-math-symbols-latex` doesn't show any completion, eg. after typing `\om` where at least `\omega` is a relevant completion.

The command `company-complete-common` show me some LaTeX's command completion, but no LaTeX's symbols.

How do I get symbols completion ?

That is my org hook foc LaTeX completion :

```
  (defun my-latex-mode-setup ()
    (setq-local company-backends
        (append '(company-math-symbols-latex company-latex-commands)
            company-backends))
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-z TAB") 'company-math-symbols-latex))
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-latex-mode-setup)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To complete latex symbol in org-mode you need an additional line.

```lisp
(setq company-math-allow-latex-symbols-in-faces t)
```